# Trouble identifying "Tombstone exists for queued item; deleting." in ipad logs

Tags: ios, ipad

Playing around with my apple device logs and getting interested in identifying different events.  Many I seem to be able to figure out with a google search and a bit of reading.  However, this one is eluding me.  This is only a small snippet of these events.  The log was compiling at a decent pace, when these particular lines began to appear in a much more rapid manner.

-The device is not jailbroken, running out of the box ios
-No apps running at time of log
-I do not use Icloud

````
 Jan 17 22:40:03 A-iPad suggestd(CoreSuggestionsInternals)[388] <Notice>: Tombstone exists for queued item; deleting.
 Jan 17 22:40:03 A-iPad suggestd(CoreSuggestionsInternals)[388] <Notice>: Tombstone exists for queued item; deleting.
 Jan 17 22:40:03 A-iPad suggestd(CoreSuggestionsInternals)[388] <Notice>: Tombstone exists for queued item; deleting.
 Jan 17 22:40:03 A-iPad suggestd(CoreSuggestionsInternals)[388] <Notice>: Tombstone exists for queued item; deleting.
 Jan 17 22:40:03 A-iPad suggestd(CoreSuggestionsInternals)[388] <Notice>: Tombstone exists for queued item; deleting.
 Jan 17 22:40:03 A-iPad suggestd(CoreSuggestionsInternals)[388] <Notice>: Tombstone exists for queued item; deleting.
 Jan 17 22:40:03 A-iPad suggestd(CoreSuggestionsInternals)[388] <Notice>: Tombstone exists for queued item; deleting.
 Jan 17 22:40:03 A-iPad suggestd(CoreSuggestionsInternals)[388] <Notice>: Tombstone exists for queued item; deleting.```


This was also referenced immediately after the above 
```MobileSafari(CoreMotion)[326] <Notice>: {"msg":"CLGyroBiasEstimatorClientRemote::unregisterWithGyroBiasEstimatorPrivate", "event":"activity", "client":"0x111b2e550"}```
````

Answer (score 1):

See: [Tombstone (data store)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombstone_(data_store)).

In brief, a tombstone is a token in a distributed data storage system that gets put in place when a record is deleted. It's needed for synchronizing different stores on the distributed system. For example, if record 'A' is deleted on one store, when the system tries to sync it may see another copy of record 'A' on a different store, and it won't know that the record was deleted from the first. It might unwittingly sync record 'A' back to the first store, effectively undeleting it. The tombstone tells the system that record 'A' was deleted on the first store, so that the system can sync that deletion to the other stores appropriately.

Comment: Would these just be normal system processes that I wouldn't have to authorize?  At the time, I had made no deletions of files, as I really don't keep anything stored on the device, and I had no apps running at the time of the logs.  I had closed them all before initiating the log in order to begin discerning what programs do what.  Also, this device is not jailbroken and is running out of the box ios.

Comment: It's most likely core data storage from some system app — maybe iCloud-related, since that's the most obvious distributed system — that you're not supposed to know about and don't have any direct access to. But even if you were doing database programming directly you  probably wouldn't be working with tombstones; they are a low-level book-keeping construct that's usually invisible to the developer. You'd just delete a record, and the database would handle all the fidgety bits of maintaining correct synchronization.